# MySQL IF statement checking multiple rows

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am using a MySQL procedure where the result of `SELECT * FROM progress where case_id = current_data;` is the following table.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id_progress | task_id | case_id | user_id | current |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 247         | 4       | 1002    | 1       | 0       |
| 248         | 1       | 1002    | 1       | 0       |
| 249         | 2       | 1002    | 1       | 0       |
| 250         | 3       | 1002    | 1       | 0       |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I wanted to create a IF statement to check the `current` table. If all rows are equals to `'0'` or not.

But I have no idea how to proceed. Using a select in the IF statement 
seems to me strange.

Comment: by all rows equal to 0, do you mean all rows have current equal to 0? what other values can current have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to aggregate your results, so that the SELECT just returns one value.

For example, the following returns the number of NonZero rows.  You then want to check that there are no NonZero rows.

```
IF ( (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN current = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        FROM progress
       WHERE case_id = current_data
     )
     =
     0
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM current
             WHERE current_data = 0), 1, 0)
```

or

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM current WHERE current_data = 0) THEN
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM progress where case_id = current_data;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    //some other code 
END;
END IF;
```